# How to convert this Octave/Matlab code to Python 3.7.4?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, octave, blender

I have some working Octave/Matlab code that I'm trying to get working / converted to Python 3.7.4, so I can use it in Blender 2.82 which **uses Python 3.7.4**.

The working Octave/Matlab code is:

```matlab
c=[7,-2,-4,-8]

[rw col]= size(c); %get size a array

num_of_loops=5 %number of loops to iterate
a= zeros(num_of_loops,col); %allocate memory to array
b= zeros(1,(rw*col)); %allocate memory to array

a(1,:)=c; %add c array to 1st row in array 

for n=1:num_of_loops
  n
  a = c .+ [c(end).*(0:4)].'; 
  b = vec (a.', 2);
endfor

b=reshape(a',1,[]);
```

Which gives me the correct output of:

```
c= 
7   -2  -4  -8

a=
 7  -2  -4  -8
-1  -10 -12 -16
-9  -18 -20 -24
-17 -26 -28 -32
-25 -34 -36 -40

b=
7   -2  -4  -8  -1  -10 -12 -16 -9  -18 -20 -24 -17 -26 -28 -32 -25 -34 -36 -40
```

(**If you need the if / then / else commands** here's the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244381/making-a-for-loop-more-efficient-in-octave?noredirect=1#comment106561987_60244381).)

I tried the [online convert octave/matlab to python converter](https://ompclib.appspot.com/m2py) and it gives me the code below (which doesn't fully work). How can I fix the Python 3.x code to get it to work in Blender 2.82 which uses Python 3.7.4?

```py
c = mcat([7, -2, -4, -8]); print c

[rw, col] = size(c)#get size a array

num_of_loops = 5; print num_of_loops#number of loops to iterate
a = zeros(num_of_loops, col)#allocate memory to array
b = zeros(1, (rw * col))#allocate memory to array

a(1, mslice[:]).lvalue = c#add c array to 1st row in array

for n in mslice[1:num_of_loops]:
    n()
    mcat([c(end) *elmul* (mslice[0:4])]).T
    b = vec(a.T, 2)
    end

    b = reshape(a.cT, 1, mcat([]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given MATLAB/Octave code can be minimized (see also the comment on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244381)) to:

```matlab
c = [7, -2, -4, -8]
a = c .+ [c(end).*(0:4)].'
b = vec(a.', 2)
```

The corresponding output is:

```
c =
   7  -2  -4  -8

a =
    7   -2   -4   -8
   -1  -10  -12  -16
   -9  -18  -20  -24
  -17  -26  -28  -32
  -25  -34  -36  -40

b =
    7 -2 -4 -8 -1 -10 -12 -16 -9 -18 -20 -24 -17 -26 -28 -32 -25 -34 -36 -40
```

The MATLAB/Octave code can be easily transferred to Python using [NumPy](https://numpy.org). There are a lot of resources on "NumPy for MATLAB users" which can be found online, e.g. [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) one from the developers themselves.

My solution would look like this:

```py
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[7, -2, -4, -8]])
a = c + (np.expand_dims(c[0][-1] * np.arange(5), 1))
b = a.reshape(1, np.prod(a.shape))

# Just for console output 
print('c = ')
print(c, '\n')
print('a = ')
print(a, '\n')
print('b = ')
print(b, '\n')
```

The output of that code is:

```
c = 
[[ 7 -2 -4 -8]] 

a = 
[[  7  -2  -4  -8]
 [ -1 -10 -12 -16]
 [ -9 -18 -20 -24]
 [-17 -26 -28 -32]
 [-25 -34 -36 -40]] 

b = 
[[  7 -2 -4 -8 -1 -10 -12 -16 -9 -18 -20 -24 -17 -26 -28 -32 -25 -34 -36 -40]]
```

It's up to you to check, if NumPy is supported in your environment. If not, I'd assume, a solution might get a lot more complicated.

Hope that helps.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
Octave:      5.1.0
----------------------------------------
```